# How can I create a clickable grid in java?

Tags: java

I'm creating Conway's game of life in java, and I want to make a clickable on screen grid to toggle the cells on/off before pressing start. What is the best way to do this? A grid of JButtons won't do it for me as it looks horrible (unless theres a way of changing how they look?)

any help is greatly appreciated - thanks!

Comment: You can extend a `JPanel` class, call it `ClickableJPanel`, or something. That's what I'd go for, at least. If needing complete control over all cells.

Comment: Right, there's ways of receiving X, Y event directly.  Just process the clicks and you can make your own grid easily.

Comment: Your question appears to be broad and you should sub-divide this problem into its requisite smaller steps, including listening for mouse clicks, drawing spots,... and then try to solve each step one at a time. Then if stuck, come back with your code and your more specific question.

Answer (score 1):

I would use raw graphics 2D draw commands to manually draw rectangles in AWT for Conway's Game of Life. You can still listen to click events for the frame and then use the x and y coordinates to calculate the cell. It will be a lot faster than using UI components, as well.